# React - "this" becomes undefined during render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I have a basic index.js page that contains the App wrapped in a BrowserRouter like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Within my App.js I have a conditional render to handle login:

```
if(!this.state.loggedIn) return (
      <Container className="pt-5">
        <Login from={this.props.location}/>
      </Container>
    )
    else return (
      <div>
        <Menu/>
        <Container className="pt-5">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
            <Route path="/morestuff" component={MoreStuff}/>
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
```

Within my Login.js I have a simple form with a button that triggers an arrow function to validate the login.  At the end of the arrow function, it calls **this.setState()** which triggers a re-render.  The render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
        const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
        return <Redirect to={from}/>
    }
    else return (
        <Container fluid>
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="password"/>
            <Button onClick={this.authenticate}>Submit</Button>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

So my question then is:  Why do I recieve "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" with specific reference to this line:

```
if (this.state.loggedIn)
```

I feel like something is happening out of order.  In my mind, this seems pretty logical: the Login control is rendered in App.js, the user presses the login button which changes the state of Login causing it to re-render with a Redirect which causes the browser to navigate and App.js to reload with new content.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you declare the state.loggedIn within your class?

Comment: @Rob share your App.js component completely

Comment: Yes, it is initialised to false which allows the login form to correctly render the first time. There are no errors when it renders which is why it's strange that an error suddenly appears when it is forced to re-render from the state change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error about accessing `this.state`, but about accessing `this.props.location.state`.

You are not passing a `location` prop to `Login` (`<Login from={this.props.location}/>`), so when you try to access `this.props.location.state` inside `Login` you get the error:

```
const { from } = this.props.location.state <== || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
```

You need to do this instead:

```
<Container className="pt-5">
  <Login location={this.props.location}/>
</Container>
```

Comment: You are correct.  The error messages had me on a wild goose chase looking at the wrong line of code.  Once I removed the "this.props.location.state" statements the error disappeared.  Sometimes it just needs a fresh set of eyes :)